# Display a 32 bit unsigned int image with Tkinter and Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, tkinter, vtk

If I have a 2D numpy array of 32bit integers, where each refers to a pixels RGBA values(8bit each), generated like so in C++

```
const Colour *colours = getColourArray();
Uint32 *pixels = getPixelBuffer();
for(size_t i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++) {
    pixels[i] = (Uint32)(colour[i].r() << 24 | colour[i].g() << 16 | colour[i].b() << 8 | 255);
}
```

In SDL we can update a texture with the `pixels` buffer above(where Colour is just a simple RGB struct).

How can such a texture be displayed with Tkinter and Python3?

EDIT: I have access to VTK8 if a VTK renderer can be embedded in a Tkinter window or frame.

Comment: Use the Tkinter canvas drawing pixel by pixel or generate an image (not sure what module to use here, though this is the harder way unless you want to generate only one image and have it cached.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: make a function that can do the pixel conversion:

```
def convert(pixel):
    '''convert 32-bit integer to 4 8-bit integers'''
    return list(int(pixel).to_bytes(4, 'big'))
```

Step 2: convert your 2D array into a 3D array (I'll assume you named the array you have "data").

```
import numpy as np
new = np.empty((data.size, 4))
old_shape = data.shape
data.shape = -1, # reshape into a 1D array

for i in range(data.size):
    new[i] = convert(data[i])

new.shape = old_shape + (-1,) # reshape into 3D
```

Step 3: Load the numpy array into an image.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(new, mode='RGBA')
```

Step 4a: If all you want to do is see or save the image then you can use PIL to do that; no tkinter needed.

```
img.show() # display in your default image viewer
img.save('data.png') # save to disk
```

Step 4b: If you do need to load it into tkinter then you can use `ImageTk.PhotoImage` to load it into a Label widget:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

lbl = tk.Label()
lbl.pimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
lbl.config(image=lbl.pimg)
lbl.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With Cython this is quite workable.